# Adding an element (vector) to a list in rpy2

Tags: python, list, r, vector, rpy2

In R, I can add elements to a list easily:

```
mylist = list()
mylist[[1]] = c(1,2)
mylist[[2]] = c(2,3)
mylist[[length(mylist)+1]] = c(3,4)
```

How do I do this in rpy2? I am using rpy2 2.1.9. I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
a = robjects.r('list()')
b = robjects.IntVector([1,2])
a[0] = b
IndexError: Index out of range.
a[1] = b
IndexError: Index out of range.
aa = a.__add__(b) # But this makes a list out of the vector
aa.r_repr()
'list(1L, 2L)'
# We wanted something like the following instead:
aaa = robjects.r('list(c(1,2))')
aaa.r_repr()
'list(c(1, 2))'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use R's "[[<-" operator, you'll have to call the method rx2()
(see [assigning, R-style][1]).

In rpy2-2.2.0dev, you can do `a.rx2[1] = b`.

[1]: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/vector.html#assigning-r-style assigning, R-style

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help in appending to a list.

Comment: Being advertised as the equivalent of the R code you are trying to emulate, it should...

Comment: a.rx2(1) = b does not work, as you can't assign to a function call.

Comment: The documentation the link points to suggests something like a.rx2[1] = b

Comment: @lgautier, a.rx2[1]=b gives AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: I have Python 2.6.6, rpy2 2.1.9 (latest on macports). That must be it.

Comment: lgautier, I have attempted to edit the answer to reflect the solution. I will accept it once the edit is approved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you can do this with the current version of rpy2, but you can try out the rpy2.rlike.container.TaggedList class, which can act as an R list and supports appending, removing and retagging items. As far as I can tell, there must be a bug in the assignment for lists and vectors.